# SICP - Is my recursive definition of an iterative process for factorial bad?

Tags: iteration, lisp, racket, factorial, sicp

I am studying the awesome book SICP. Despite being great, it is a really tough book. I am having problems with the long tail recursion,id est, a recursion definition for an iterative process.
    The book presents this iterative procedure for factorial:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (fact-iter 1 1 n))
(define (fact-iter product counter max-count)
  (if (> counter max-count)
      product
      (fact-iter (* counter product)
                 (+ counter 1)
                 max-count)))
```

I tried doing one approach without looking at the book example. I got this:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (factorial-iter n 1 n))

(define (factorial-iter a product counter)
  (if (= counter 0)
      product
      (factorial-iter (- a 1)
                      (* product a)
                      (- counter 1))))
```

Is my approach wrong in some sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing *wrong* in your approach, it calculates correctly the factorial, there is only something superfluous. You can note that the two variables `a` and `counter` have *always* the same value since they are updated always in the same way. So you can get rid of one of them, and simplify your function in this way:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (factorial-iter n 1))

(define (factorial-iter a product)
  (if (= a 0)
      product
      (factorial-iter (- a 1)
                      (* product a))))
```

Finally, to stay on the safe side, you can change the test for the termination to see if `a` is less than or equal to 0, so the function will not loop endless with a negative argument:

```
(define (factorial-iter a product)
  (if (<= a 0)
      product
      (factorial-iter (- a 1)
                      (* product a))))
```